# Cannot get my java project to build org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I just received a project to work on and I'm trying to run "mvn clean install" in order to get all the plugins and dependencies installed and I am getting this error. Any ideas?

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project EHS_ITO_BACKEND: Compilation failure
>   No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPhQu.png)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>D</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.9</source>
          <target>1.9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <artifactId></artifactId>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven needs a JDK in order to compile your project. Maven uses `JAVA_HOME` to find a JDK, based on this message ...

> Compilation failure No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

... your `JAVA_HOME` either does not exist or it does not point at a JDK.

If you run `mvn -version` it will tell you what it is using for Java. You *should* see something like this:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

If you are not seeing that then you must set your JAVA_HOME. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html):

On Unix:

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
```

On Windows

```
Right click My Computer and select Properties.

On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02.
```